# Unit testing Python Azure Function: How do I construct a mock test request message with a JSON payload?

Tags: python, azure, unit-testing

I want to unit test my Python Azure function. I'm following the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python#unit-testing).

The documentation mocks the call to the function as follows

```py
req = func.HttpRequest(
            method='GET',
            body=None,
            url='/api/HttpTrigger',
            params={'name': 'Test'})
```

I would like to do this but with the parameters passed as a JSON object so that I can follow the `req_body = req.get_json()` branch of the function code. I guessed I would be able to do this with a function call like

```py
req = func.HttpRequest(
            method='GET',
            body=json.dumps({'name': 'Test'}),
            url='/api/HttpTrigger',
            params=None)
```

If I construct the call like this, `req.get_json()` fails with the error message `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`.

How do I construct the request with JSON input parameters? It should be trivial but I'm clearly missing something obvious.

Comment: `body` expects a byte string, while you provide a string. Try something like `body=json.dumps({'name': 'Test'}).encode('utf8')`.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen: If I add the encoding as suggested, I receive the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decode'` when calling `req.get_json()`

Comment: Yeah, I didn't pay attention that this was a GET request. Check the answer by @JoeyCai - this is the correct solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I construct my mock call as follows:

```py
import json


req = func.HttpRequest(
            method='POST',
            body=json.dumps({'name': 'Test'}).encode('utf8'),
            url='/api/HttpTrigger',
            params=None)
```

Then I am able to make a successful call to `req.get_json()`. Thanks to @MrBeanBremen and @JoeyCai for pointing me in the correct direction i.e. don't call `GET` and make the message a byte string.

Answer (score 0):

> Any HTTP request message is allowed to contain a message body, and thus must parse messages with that in mind. Server semantics for GET, however, are restricted such that a body, if any, has no semantic meaning to the request. The requirements on parsing are separate from the requirements on method semantics.

For your http request, it is a `GET` method. **You can send a request body with GET but it should not have any meaning.**

So use the below code to construct a mock HTTP request with a json payload. For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python#unit-testing).

```
req = func.HttpRequest(
    method='GET',
    body=None,
    url='/api/HttpTrigger',
    params={'name': 'Test'})
```

**Update:**

For `Post` request, you could send json payload with `body=json.dumps({'name': 'Test'}).encode('utf8')` while body expects a **byte string**:

```
req = func.HttpRequest(
    method='POST',
    body=json.dumps({'name': 'Test'}).encode('utf8'),
    url='/api/HttpTrigger',
    params=None)
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment but I'm not sure I understand it. If I construct the request like this, then a subsequent call to `req.get_json()` fails with `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decode'`. I really want to test the branch of my code that gets triggered with a successful call to `req.get_json()`

Comment: Maybe you could show us more of your code to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen, I'm just following the Microsoft example I linked to at the top of my query. There is a call in the Function (in `__init__.py`) which calls ```name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:``` I wanted to test a successful call of `req_body = req.get_json()`. I posted the call below which combines your encoding and @joeyCai 's advice not to use `GET`

Comment: That would only make sense for a POST request, not for a GET request. As @JoeyCai wrote, in your case (GET request) you shall pass the parameters in the `params` dict.